# Java- GWT Client class file changes not reflecting when deployed through WAS

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I have some GWT RPC Client files and I will compile them in Eclipse and want to replace these client class files in WebSphere. But When I compile in Eclipse, multiple class file will be generated for single source file like $file1.class, $file1.class for file1.java. And in deployment folder of WebSphere when I replace all these files changes are not refelcting even after restarting the server.

Thanks

Comment: In other words How to deploy java compiled classes contain dollar signs on WAS?

Comment: Can Anyone reply please